# Backup failure alerting in GCP

Tags: google-compute-engine, rsnapshot

I was try to configure the snapshot failure alerting in GCP but unfortunately it wont work at all. I scheduled the snapshot for disks and delete the VM...but still my snapshot scheduler takes snapshots...Looks like the snapshot scheduler is taking  blind snapshots Of disk even the disk is not attached to VM !!

Is there any solution to fail the Snapshot so i can create the policy for failure of snapshot disk?

Answer (score 0):

Could you verify if the option `Deletion rule` is uncheck from the Disks options on the VM creation? In reality, snapshot is created from a disk, not from the VM itself. That may explain this behavior if this option is uncheck (disk preserved when VM is deleted).

I tried both cases and I got an error `resource <...> is not ready` only when the disks is deleted with the VM.

[Disks - Deletion rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7VBw.png)

Comment: I have tried this as well but it wont work for me...Question to you -Is there any other way that i can take my data backup for my gce? other than snapshot...

Comment: To be honest, I always used snapshots for backup my personal projects, that was enough for my needs. However, I found something interesting from a 3rd party website if you have data to backup using Google Coldline Storage (regardless the VM) https://scotthelme.co.uk/easy-cheap-and-secure-backup-with-google-cloud-platform/

Comment: I also suggest you to file this unexpected behavior on : https://issuetracker.google.com